# Is it possible to use an unwind segue from a single modal view controller back to one of multiple instances of the same source view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboard, unwind-segue

My Storyboard layout is such that I have `MainVC` connected to `ModalVC` via a segue that presents it modally.

However, programmatically, at runtime, I instantiate five instances of `MainVC` in total.

As a result, all five instances of `MainVC`, with the same identifier, are connected to `ModalVC`.

I need to change properties in `MainVC` after performing some actions in `ModalVC` and dismissing it, and there appear to be various ways to do this via segues.

The top answer here is quite detailed and explains the implementation of using an unwind segue but only in the scenario of there being one source view controller:
[Passing data with unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313747/passing-data-with-unwind-segue)

**My question is:** will using a segue, like in that answer, or any other way, work in my situation, with multiple instances of the same `MainVC` (same identifier) attached to a single instance of `ModalVC`?

Will the unwind segue only transfer data or perform actions in the single `MainVC` instance that initiated it? Or will it end up affecting all five `MainVC` instances because the `MainVC` instances have the same identifiers? If the latter, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a comprehensive [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) on how unwind segues work and how the destination view controller is determined, but, in summary, the process examines the view controller navigation hierarchy to find the first view controller that can handle the unwind segue and is willing to do so.

In your case, this would be the `MainVC` instance that presented the `ModalVC` that is unwinding. The unwind segue cannot be handled by a view controller instance that is not in the navigation hierarchy (e.g. An instance of `MainVC` that did not present the `ModalVC`)