# ViewController Pushing Swift From One VC to Another VC And Returning back

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Consider two view controller `Controller1` and `Controller2`, I have created a form of many `UITextField` in controller 1, in that when a user clicks a particular `UITextField` it moves to Controller2 and he selects the data there.

After selecting the data in `Controller2` it automatically moves to `Controller1`, while returning from controller2 to controller1 other `UITextfield` data got cleared and only the selected data from controller2 is found. I need all the data to be found in the `UITextfield` after selecting.

Here is the code for returning from `Controller2` to `Controller1`

```
 if(Constants.SelectedComplexName != nil)
  {
      let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NewUserLogin", bundle: nil)
      let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewUser") as! NewUserRegistrationViewController
      self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: add your VC1 Code and how will you pop from VC2 to VC1

Comment: @Anbu.karthik my VC1 code    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NewUserLogin", bundle: nil)
            let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ComplexList") as! ComplexSearchViewController
            self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: You may want to use an unwind segue. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313747/passing-data-with-unwind-segue

Comment: *only the selected data from controller2 is found* - How you are fetching the data from controller2 to controller1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass messages you need to implement `Delegate`.

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didUpdateData(controller: SecondViewController, data: YourDataModel)
}
//This is your Data Model and suppose it contain 'name', 'email', 'phoneNumber'
class YourDataModel: NSObject {
    var name: String? //
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var email: String?
}
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    var data: YourDataModel?
    var nameTextField: UITextField?
    var phoneNumberTextField: UITextField?
    var emailTextField: UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        callWebApi()
    }

    func callWebApi() {
        //After Success Fully Getting Data From Api
        //Set this data to your global object and then call setDataToTextField()
        //self.data = apiResponseData
        self.setDataToTextField()
    }

    func setDataToTextField() {
        self.nameTextField?.text = data?.name
        self.phoneNumberTextField?.text = data?.phoneNumber
        self.emailTextField?.text = data?.email
    }

    func openNextScreen() {
        let vc2 = SecondViewController()//Or initialize it from storyboard.instantiate method
        vc2.delegate = self//tell second vc to call didUpdateData of this class.
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
    }

    //This didUpdateData method will call automatically from second view controller when the data is change
    func didUpdateData(controller: SecondViewController, data: YourDataModel) {

    }
}
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?

    func setThisData(d: YourDataModel) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        //Right After Going Back tell your previous screen that data is updated.
        //To do this you need to call didUpdate method from the delegate object.
        if let del = self.delegate {
            del.didUpdateData(controller: self, data: d)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
push your view controller instead of a present like this  


if(Constants.SelectedComplexName != nil)
 {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NewUserLogin", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewUser") as! NewUserRegistrationViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
 }
```

and then pop after selecting your data from vc2 like this

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

and if you are not using navigation controller then you can simply call `Dismiss` method

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    print("updaae your data")
}
```

Comment: This is a good explanation of how to push/pop, but does not show how the data entered on VC2 will be returned for display in VC1.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it, but it usually depends on how you move from VC#1 to VC#2 and back.

(1) The code you posted implies you have a Storyboard with both view controllers. In this case create a segue from VC#1 to VC#2 and an "unwind" segue back. Both are fairly easy to do. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313747/passing-data-with-unwind-segue) provided in the comments does a good job of showing you, but, depending on (1) how much data you wish to pass back to VC#1 and (2) if you wish to execute a function on VC#2, you could also do this:

VC#1:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowVC2" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? VC2ViewController {
            vc.VC1 = self
        }
    }
}
```

VC#2:

```
weak var VC1:VC1ViewController!

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isMovingFromParentViewController {
        VC1.executeSomeFunction()
    }
}
```

Basically you are passing the *entire* instance of VC1 and therefore have access to everything that isn't marked `private`.

(2) If you are presenting/dismissing VC#2 from VC#1, use the `delegate` style as described by one of the answers.

VC#1:

```
var VC2 = VC2ViewController()

extension VC1ViewController: VC2ControlllerDelegate {
    func showVC2() {
        VC2.delegate = self
        VC2.someData = someData
        present(VC2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    function somethingChanged(sender: VC2ViewController) {
        // you'll find your data in sender.someData, do what you need
    }
}
```

VC#2:

```
protocol VC2Delegate {
    func somethingChanged(sender: VC2ViewController) {
        delegate.somethingChanged(sender: self)
    }
}
class DefineViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate:DefineVCDelegate! = nil
    var someData:Any!

    func dismissMe() {
        delegate.somethingChanged(sender: self)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

Basically, you are making VC#1 be a delegate to VC2. I prefer the declaration syntax in VC#2 for `delegate because if you forget to set VC#1 to be a delegate for VC#2, you test will force an error at runtime.