# Passing Stepper value to another view controller

Tags: swift, view, controller, stepper

Pretty self explanatory code, my issue is the first print shows the correct value but the second print always show 0. I'm trying to pass the value of the stepper to my next view controller (calcVC).

Edit: Forgot to mention that my issue happens when I click a button which triggers an unwind segue to CalcVC which is when I loose the value. Also, this code is in TableViewCellVC and my unwind segue is from TableViewVC to CalcVC which is why I'm having issue on CalcVC.

Final Edit: Fixed it by creating a global variable

```
    var stepperValue = 1


@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {

    stepperValue = Int(stepper.value)

    print(stepperValue)

    stepperLabel.text = String(stepperValue)

    let CalcVC = CalculatorVC()

    stepperValue = CalcVC.calcVCStepperValue

    print(stepperValue)
}
```

Comment: What is the value of ```calcVCStepperValue```?

Comment: simply var CalcVCStepperValue = Int()

Comment: So basically you were setting the stepperValue to 0 as you indirectly set the value of stepperValue to Int(), which is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the value of `stepperValue` to `CalcVC.calcVCStepperValue`. At the moment you are just creating `CalcVC` then printing out the default value of `calcVCStepperValue`.

```
let CalcVC = CalculatorVC()
CalcVC.calcVCStepperValue = stepperValue
stepperValue = CalcVC.calcVCStepperValue
print(stepperValue)
```

If you’re doing this with segues you can’t create a new instance of the view controller. Instead you need to implement the `prepareForSegue` function on the view controller from which you are unwinding and use the segue parameter to access the `destinationViewController`.

There is an existing answer for this at [Passing data with unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313747/passing-data-with-unwind-segue)

Comment: According to breakpoints, this works however I neglected to mention that my issue happens when I click a button which triggers and unwind segue to CalcVC which is when I loose the value. I updated my original post to reflect that

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: Fixed by creating a global variable. Thanks