# Dismiss my view controller but "prepare" the view controller underneath

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a modally-presented `ViewController` that has a `UITableView` inside it. When the user clicks "Days", it shows this view controller (modally). Here's my Storyboard:

[image]

[image]

What I want to do is, when I click one of the cells in the table view in the modal, I want to dismiss the modal, but also load new data in the root view controller.

How can I have access to the root view controller from a segued view controller?

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! DayView
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destinationVC.day = days![indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

I want something like what I've written above, but while my modal does get dismissed, but what I want is for somehow the code in the prepare function to fire when a TableViewCell is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are in the right path,you need to add two more functions 1. [`unwindsegue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313747/passing-data-with-unwind-segue/35314768) and one this is not destination its source so you need change to source from destination.

```
 // MARK: - Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.source as! DayView
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destinationVC.day = days![indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

for Reference : [How to Pass Data in an Unwind Segue](https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/how-to-pass-data-in-an-unwind-segue-swift-3-1c3fa095cde1)

Answer (score 1):

**A shorter and simpler method than protocol/delegate is to create a closure:**

For sending a String back, In First ViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewControllerB = segue.destination as? ViewControllerB {
        viewControllerB.callback = { message in
            
            //Do what you want in here!

        }
    }
}
```

In ViewControllerB:

```
var callback : ((String) -> Void)?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    callback?("Your Data")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```