# TableView only adds one cell

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying add data dynamically to a new cell every time the unwindsegue method is triggered. So far it's only creating one cell. I cant't figure out what i am doing wrong. Iv'e tried implementeing a delegate and data source, but i get a redundant error. FYI: I am using Storyboard.

View Controller 2

```
class NewPasswordViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

var passName:String?
var passWord:String?


//var passWordDataArray:[Password]

var NewPassWord = Password()
    


@IBAction func getPassWordName(_ sender: UITextField) {
    passName = sender.text
    if passName != nil{
        NewPassWord.name = passName!
    }
}
@IBAction func getPassWord(_ sender: UITextField) {
    passWord = sender.text
    if passWord != nil{
        NewPassWord.password = passWord!
    }
}


@IBAction func saveNewPassWord(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)  {
    
    let vc = segue.destination as! PassWordTableViewController
    
    vc.passwords.append(NewPassWord)
    
 }

}
```

View Controller 1

```
class PassWordTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    var passwords = [Password]()

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return passwords.count
    }

    // return the number of rows for the table
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return passwords.count
    }
    // Provide a cell for each row
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        // Fetch a cell of the appropriate type.
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell", for: indexPath) as! PassWordViewCell
        
        let thePassWord = passwords[indexPath.row]

        //Configure the cell's contents.
        cell.passWordName?.text = thePassWord.name
        
        return cell
    }
    
    @IBAction func unWindToPassWordTable(unWindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        
    }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see only one cell in your `tableView` is because whenever you perform segue you create a new instance of `PassWordTableViewController`, with an empty array of `Password`.

You have to use the `unwind` function to pass back the data from `ViewControlletr1` to `ViewController2`, then append the new data and pass it together with your segue.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35314768/14516049) to see an implementation example.

Comment: Iv'e tried this, however i am unable to downcast a view controller to a table view controller.